# Which scripting language to use to asynchronously ssh into equipment, run several commands, parse the output, and save to a file on my computer?

Tags: bash, scripting, python, perl, logon-scripts

There are several points I'd like to stress in my question.

I'd like to login by asynchronously ssh'ing into our infrastructure equipment.  Meaning, I do not want to connect to only one device, do all the tasks I need, disconnect, then connect to the next device.  I want to connect to several devices at once in order to make the process as fast as possible.

By equipment I mean 'infrastructure equipment' and *not* servers.  I say this because I will not have the luxury of saving files to the device then transferring them to myself with scp or another method.  The output of the scripts that are run will have to be saved directly to my computer.

I will also not be able to use keys in order to automate the login process.  The password entry will need to be automated through the script.

The output of the commands that are run will need to be cleaned up and parsed.  Also I want the outputs of each device to be combined into one nice and neat file, not a separate file for each device.

This will all be done from a linux box, using ssh, into devices that all use linux'ish proprietary OSes.

My guess is the answer to my question will either be a Bash, Perl, or Python script but I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask and to hear the reasons why one way is better than another.

Thanks everyone.

EXTRA CREDIT:
With you answer, include links to resources that will help create the script I described in the language that you suggested.

Comment: python + fabric. That's essentially what it's for.

Comment: The requirements of `Also I want the outputs of each device to be combined into one nice and neat file`, and `I want to connect to several devices at once` are pretty close to being mutually exclusive.  The tool would almost certainly need to write per-device files and then merge them somehow.

Comment: @Zoredache thank you.  That gives me the strategy to use once I begin coding.

Comment: @Sirex thank you, implementing that as we speak to test out.

Answer (score 3):

[Parallel SSH (pssh)](http://www.theether.org/pssh/) is perfectly suited to this task, it executes the same command on multiple hosts in parallel. By default pssh will use 32 parallel threads but this number can be increased if required.

Output from the hosts can be logged on the machine that pssh is run from. When logging output pssh will create a text file per host, however your bash script could easily concatenate these.

```bash
# pwd
/home/fujin

# cat ips.txt
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3

# cat commands.txt
hostname
date
uname -a

# cat script.sh
rm -rf /tmp/pssh-output
mkdir -p /tmp/pssh-output
xargs -I {} pssh -h /home/fujin/ips.txt -o /tmp/pssh-output {} < /home/fujin/commands.txt
cat /tmp/pssh-output/* > /tmp/pssh-output/output.txt

# /bin/sh script.sh
Success on 192.168.0.1
Success on 192.168.0.2
Success on 192.168.0.3

# ls /tmp/pssh-output
192.168.0.1  192.168.0.2  192.168.0.3  output.txt
```

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you for the suggestion and example code.  I will be testing this solution out along with testing out fabric.

Comment: This script lacks the code to put in the password for logging in with SSH.  I'm currently looking through the documentation to see if automating pw entry is possible with pssh.

Comment: I don't believe it does, it expects to use public key authentication with ssh-agent. You might want to edit your question and call out the need for keyboard-interactive authentication if that's a requirement.